Flutter iOS Local Network permission checking failed after updating my app's iOS deployment target to 13.1
Encountered issue where permission_handler library keep getting the status of Permission.nearbyWifiDevices.status as false.
When I first open the app, it did ask permission and I've accepted it. Also verified from Settings > Privacy & Security > My app > Local Network is enabled.
But checking the permission using permission_handler keep getting false after I update the iOS deployment target. As workaround I tried checking via native code, referring to this solution: iOS native checking Local Network
Is there some changes done by Apple for newer iOS version that require additional step to be done for this Local Network permission? And also, what is the best library to use to connect Flutter iOS app to an Access Point? Currently using wifi_iot to connect to the WiFi SSID

From what I've read, nearbyWiFiDevices and Local Network permissions are different permissions.
If you take a look at Permission enum documentation, it says that this permission is available only on Android 13+(i.e not on iOS).
Here is an Apple article explaining what is Local Network permission.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/102229
And here is a way to "control" when to show a Local Network permission dialog.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663768
As for the best package for AP connection, you are pretty much using it already. In my experience, the connection you make is spotty, specifically the part when you connect to an AP. The next best thing is to create a connection method yourself using native code, unfortunately.
